# Is it safe to pass req as a variable in res.render in expressJs?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using NodeJs+ ExpressJs + Handlebars to build a website. When rendering a page I need to pass 3 things everytime : isAuthenticated, userEmail, and FlashMsg.
Instead of This :

```
res.render('/webPage', {isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(), userEmail: req.user.email, flashMsg: req.flash()});
```

Is it safe to do it like that so everythings will be accessible on the page?:

```
res.render('/webPage', {req:req});
```

Is it too much stuff passed to the page or it's not a problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: If you tell us why you would want to do that we might be able to tell you a better way to do it

Comment: My route need to pass all 3 things to the handlebars pages. In the page I need to check if req.isAuthenticated, I need to get req.user.email and req.flash() to show error messages. My concern is that if I pass  req instead of the 3 separates variable i save time but is it secure or at risk to take too much ram or something like that because req contain so much information not need?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your template is doing with the object you feed it. Is it enumerating the object's properties? If so, that's probably a bad idea. Is your template going to try and serialize the `req` object into JSON? That's also bad.

If you want to be both safe and have concise code at the same time, you could only include the properties your template cares about like this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
res.render('/webpage',
    _.pluck(req, ['isAuthenticated', 'user', 'flash'])
);
```